# What is the word for interior with a circle

Tags: word-request, mathematics

I'd like to know what is the word to describe the entire interior within a circle. *Circle* is for the boundary only and does not include the interior of it.

Comment: What is the word in your native language. Have you used a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: [I'd like to know what the word is to describe etc.]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically speaking, it's a [*closed disk*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_(mathematics)).

> In geometry, a disk (also spelled disc) is the region in a plane bounded by a circle. A disk is said to be *closed* if it contains the circle that constitutes its boundary, and *open* if it does not.

Non-mathematicians will be satisfied to call it just a *disk*.

Comment: *Closed* means including the boundary (the circle). The bounded region excluding the circle itself is an *open disk*.

Comment: You should provide a link to Wikipedia. Open and closed disk do not refer to the region covered by the disk per se. It means the perimeter and the interior. A region in a plane bounded by a circle does not explain the idea.

Answer (score 2):

**Euclidean geometry** deals with figures such as: circles, rectangles, etc.
The parts inside the figures are simply an area or space.
It refers to the space inside the line or lines. Beyond that, there are all sorts of complexities I am not really trained for. :)

"Any time you need to determine the space inside a circle or the amount of space a circle covers, you can use the equation for the area of a circle. Especially for real world applications of this skill, measuring diameter is often the simplest way to start."

[space inside a circle or amount of spaced a circle covers](https://sciencing.com/calculate-area-circle-diameter-7391669.html)